# Tiny Images, No Rotation, but still get OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I've spent the morning reading through page after page of StackOverflow posts about this exact error, but the root cause of their problems always seems to be either 1) they have very large images which need to be down sampled or 2) they are suffering after one or more device rotations which cause the activity to be destroyed and recreated several times.

I'm getting this error (only very rarely), but my app only allows portrait orientation so no rotations are possible and all of my images are very small. I do have *many* images, but they are all very small. It is a calculator app, so there are images for each button. The images are only 1.9k for the mdpi and 2.8k for the hdpi. These are tiny, tiny images. I processed them through Photoshop to downsample all of them to 8bit PNGs. Here is an example of one of my images: http://geekqi.com/StackOverflow/OutOfMemoryImage.png

There are about 80 of these ImageButtons (only 40 of which are on the screen at once). I have two views, each with 40 ImageButtons and when you press a button, one of the views is hidden and the other shown (offering a Shift functionality to allow access to more functions). Each button has a standard image and a highlighted image. So, all in all I'm dealing with 160 tiny images. The biggest one is 2.8k so 160 of them would be 448k... even if the ImageButton overhead would double that size, it's less than 1MB.

Below is the stacktrace I'm receiving. It references line 296, which looks like:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/buttonRND" android:src="@drawable/image_rnd" android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
```

Here is the stack trace I'm dealing with:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mydomain.myapp/com.mydomain.myapp.CalculatorTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mydomain.myapp/com.mydomain.myapp.MyCalculator}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #296: Error inflating class <unknown>
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mydomain.myapp/com.mydomain.myapp.MyCalculator}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #296: Error inflating class <unknown>
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
       at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
       at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
       at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
       at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
       at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
       at com.mydomain.myapp.CalculatorTabActivity.setupTab(CalculatorTabActivity.java:191)
       at com.mydomain.myapp.CalculatorTabActivity.onCreate(CalculatorTabActivity.java:95)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
       ... 11 more
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #296: Error inflating class <unknown>
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:210)
       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
       at com.mydomain.myapp.MyCalculator.configureActivity(MyCalculator.java:1042)
       at com.mydomain.myapp.MyCalculator.onCreate(MyCalculator.java:1111)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
       ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:78)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
       ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:590)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:564)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:425)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
       at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
       at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:82)
       ... 40 more
```

I've read through all of the links about tracking down Android memory "leaks", but they also deal with rotation and my app doesn't allow rotation.

What can I do to find and fix this problem?

Comment: The size of the file is not particularly helpful. The size of the resulting `Bitmap` -- after decompressing the file -- is what matters.

Comment: How should I go about getting the uncompressed size of the `Bitmap` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to rotate app to get Activity restarted. It is enough to start another activity and then start the original one.

Do you keep references to your images inside your activity? How do you keep them? In fields? Are you referencing image drawables?

Comment: I'm keeping references to the the ImageButtons (which are keeping references to the images themselves). Should I be setting all of those to null in onDestroy() or something like that?

Comment: Or use WeakReference to keep references to them.

Comment: I unfortunately fall into the category of Java developers who have been writing Java since 1.0 and I've never encountered a WeakReference before Android. I'll read up on it today. However, in onCreate() I'm setting references to my ImageButtons, which means if the activity is restarted, the previous references are overwritten and shouldn't the original objects then be available for garbage collection?

Comment: This is a good reading: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: Yes you are right: references to views should have the same life-cycle as context, i.e. fields inside Activity (bur not static fields).

Comment: FOUND THE PROBLEM! The error message kept telling me the problem was on line 296 which was one of those tiny button images I described above. It turns out that one of the OTHER images (a background gradient) had not been processed through my standard Photoshop automation and so it was 111k. Processed it and now it is only 11k. I've verified that was the problem by adding it back, seeing the exception, replacing with the tiny image, it worked, replaced the big, it failed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a horrible problem I had a few months ago.

Do you have layers of transparent PNG images / backgrounds somewhere in your application (not limited to the activity you're in when the crash happens)?

What I was trying to do was minimize file size by saving image layers individually and just putting them together in the app (since I'd use some layers on their own elsewhere.)

This was producing a stack trace similar to what you're describing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: All of the images I referred to above have a tiny bit of transparency at their corners. The background doesn't have any transparency and I'm not stacking any images with transparency. At any given time I'm only showing one layer of images on top of a solid background image.